# why |x| ≤ 1/2 in this Taylor’s inequality

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Problem 14 from the MIT 18.01 course final exam:
(a) Find the Taylor series centered at a = 0 for ln(1 + x).
(b) Determine the radius of convergence for this Taylor series.
(c) Use the first two non-zero terms of the power series found in part (a) to approximate ln(3/2).
(d) Using Taylor’s inequality, give an upper bound on the error in the approximation from part (c).
the answer of part (d) is: 
The upper bound of the error in (c)’s approximation is found using
Taylor’s inequality for an approximation of n terms:

$$
|R_n(x)|\le M_n \frac{|x^{n+1}|}{(n+1)!}
$$

where x = 1/2 and n = 2. In addition,

$$
M_n \ge f^{(n+1)}(x) \implies M_2 \ge \frac{2}{(1+x)^3}
$$

for all $|x|\le 1/2$; the maximum of  $M_2$  in this range is for x = -1/2, which gives $M_2 = 16$. Putting these numbers into the above formula,

$$
R_n(.5) \le 16\frac{(.5)^3}{3!} =\frac{1}{3}
$$
Regarding part (d), the answer given states that the range of x is |x| ≤ 1/2. However, i am confused because the radius of convergence is −1 < x < 1 and x₀ = 1/2. i am wondering why the range of x is |x| ≤ 1/2 instead of −3/2 < x < 1/2.

Comment: If $−1 < x < 1,$ how do you arrive at $−3/2 < x < 1/2$? It's the same variable $x.$ In particular, at $x = -1$ the formula for $M_2$ blows up. What is less obvious is why you are allowed to restrict $x$ tighter than $−1 < x < 1$ when you set $M_2$. For that, you should review the theorem that you are using. You have overlooked important details.

Comment: Thank you, David. You are correct that -3/2 < x < 1/2 is wrong. However, Taylor’s Inequality states that if $|f^{N+1}| \le B$ for all x in the interval [c-d, c+d], where in this problem c is 1/2 and the interval should be [1/2-d, 1/2+d], then the remainder $R_N(x)$ satisfies the inequality:
$$
|R_N(x) | \le \frac{B}{(N+1)!}|x-c|^{N+1} \text{ for all } x in [c-d,c+d]
$$
I still don't understand why the answer to this problem tells me that the range of x is |x| < 1/2.

Comment: That's the detail I think you are misreading. There are different ways of bounding the error, as well as different ways of writing the method you are thinking of. I think if you look at the entire statement of the method, including the definition of $c,$ and compare it with the Taylor expansion from part (a), you'll find that $c \neq 1/2.$ If this is unclear, try editing the question to incorporate all of this information into the question itself (your previous comment, plus the missing parts of the statement you're using there) and see if someone can explain where you went wrong.